# Value binding in <script>-tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, data-binding, dotvvm

Is there a way how to use value binding in `<script>`-tags using [DotVVM](https://www.dotvvm.com/)?
I want to display the properties of the ViewModel as text. Here i want to set the labels and data of a chart using [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/).

That's what i got so far:

I'm trying to get a chart using chartjs working.
ViewModel: (The variables are getting filled with data in `PreRender()` Method)

```
private List<int> chartLabels = new List<int>();
private List<int> chartData1 = new List<int>();

public string ChartLabels
{
    get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartLabels); }
}

public string ChartData1
{
    get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartData1); }
}
```

The dothtml file:

```
<canvas id="myChart" style="padding: 0;margin: auto;display: block; "> </canvas>

<script>   
    var dataT = {
        labels: {{value: ChartLabels}},
            datasets: [{
                label: "Africa",
                data: {{value: ChartData1}},
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                borderColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        };

        var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: dataT,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: { display: true, text: 'World population per region (in millions)' },
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' } }],
                    yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' }, ticks: { stepSize: 250, beginAtZero: true } }]
                },
            }
        });  
</script>
```

Putting all together this is what i get when i open the page:

```
<script>

    var dataT = {
        labels: <!-- ko text: ChartLabels --><!-- /ko -->,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Africa",
                data: <!-- ko text: ChartData1 --><!-- /ko -->,
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                borderColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        };

        var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: dataT,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: { display: true, text: 'World population per region (in millions)' },
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' } }],
                    yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' }, ticks: { stepSize: 250, beginAtZero: true } }]
                },
            }
        });

    </script>
```

At line `<!-- ko text: ChartLabels --><!-- /ko -->,` im getting this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Does somebody know how to use proper value binding (here: displaying it as text in a `<script>`-tag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value bindings don't work in `script` elements - they are translated to Knockout JS expressions (the HTML comments you have in the code snippet).

You have two options:

1. Use resource binding: `{{resource: ChartLabels}}`
   You need to do all the conversions so it will produce a valid JavaScript expression - it just renders a string in the output HTML.
2. You may use JavaScript to get the values directly from the viewmodel:

```
var vm = dotvvm.viewModels.root.viewModel;

// you need to use () to read the value of Knockout observables 
var chartLabels = vm.ChartLabels();
```

The viewmodel on the client side is wrapped in Knockout observables, so make sure you don't forget `()` to access the value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When i try to use the second option, i get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: dotvvm is not defined` at line `var vm = dotvvm.viewModels.root.viewModel;`. Do you need more information?

Comment: The first option works, only when i'm not using SpaContentPlaceHolder in the MasterPage. Why is that?

Comment: About the second option, it looks like the code is executed before dotvvm.js is initialized. Put the script inside `<dot:InlineScript Dependencies="dotvvm">` - it will make the script load after DotVVM is loaded, and then you should wrap the script in this: 

    dotvvm.events.init.subscribe(function () {
        // place your code here
    });

It will make the script to run after DotVVM is initialized. It should also fix the problem in SPA pages - the scripts included directly in the page have problems there too.